# PHP: alternative to use() to non-anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

You can do this:

```
$external = 1;
$change = function($number) use(&$external) {
    $external = $number;
};

$change(5);
echo $external; //> 5
```

But you can not do this:

```
$external = 1;
function change($number) use(&$external) {
    $external = $number;
}
```

You'd get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'.

What are alternatives?

Comment: Is this function part of a class?

Comment: `function change($number, &$external) {`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No need to use 'use': simply put $external as a reference parameter into your named function

Comment: @AbraCadaver and @user4035: But then you need to pass `$external` when calling vs. having it be captured in the closure.

Comment: @RocketHazmat What about using the "global" keyword?

Comment: A closure can be nested inside functions, so it makes sense to have a "use" clause. However, functions cannot be nested. PHP just declares nested functions as regular functions. So, "use" makes no sense as the parent scope is global scope. So, you are trying to access global variables, which is easy with the global keyword or $GLOBALS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is only used in closures to inherit variables from the parent scope. From the manual:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

If you want to use a variable by reference in a regular function use:

```
$external = 1;

function change($number, &$external) {
    $external = $number;
}
change(5, $external);
```

Or to not pass it use it as a global (if `$external` is in global scope):

```
$external = 1;

function change($number) {
    $GLOBALS['external'] = $number;
}
change(5);
```